# program signal received "SIGTERM"

Tags: iphone

I am using `CoreData` in my iOS app. When I  kill my application and start it again then I have a method which count total number of records in all tables. But it is not executing and I have got the signal as  `program signal received "SIGTERM"`

```
-(int)getAllCount{
         NSLog(@"start");

         int returnCount=0;

         NSMutableArray *tempArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"TempFirstAid",@"TempArticles",@"TempSymptom",@"TempIndexMaster",@"TempIndexSubMaster",@"TempIndexDetails", nil];

    for (int i=0; i<[tempArr count]; i++) {

         NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:[tempArr 
         objectAtIndex:i] inManagedObjectContext:[appDelegate managedObjectContext]];

         NSFetchRequest *request2 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        [request2 setEntity:entityDesc];

        NSError *error;

        NSArray *objects = [[appDelegate managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request2 
        error:&error];

        returnCount=returnCount+[objects count];
    }
```

I am calling this method in View Did Load

Comment: Show the code that generates the problem

Comment: If you step through it with the debugger, which line gives the error?

Comment: There is not a debugger error but if I am placing a NSLog after the for loop then it is not executed means method is not getting executed completely and after some time when I terminate the application then I got the earlier signal at line "returnCount=returnCount+[objects count];"

Comment: Did you try to NSLog the error variable?

Comment: My point is that if you use the debugger to execute one line at a time, you'll know how far it gets before it stops executing.

Comment: Delete the build from your simulator/device.Quit it. Clean your code and then run again.May be it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using:

```
- (NSUInteger)countForFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request error:(NSError **)error
```

instead of getting all the objects just to get the count. I guess you are missing a part of your code since the return is missing. Another thing: it seems that you are calling this from the main thread. That might cause your app freeze and be unresponsive for a while (on large databases).

By your description of the problem, it seems that this method isn't even the problem, considering the fact that it's not actually executing.